# Android: animate circular progress drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, drawable, android-drawable

I need a drawable that looks like the rotating progress circle. That drawable I want to use for instance in an ImageView inside a GridView etc.

So, according to other posts I took the progress_medium_holo.xml from the folder \sdk\platforms\android-xx\data\res\drawable which looks like this. And I also copied the PNG files which are used by this drawable.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_outer_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="0"
             android:toDegrees="1080" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
             android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_48_inner_holo"
             android:pivotX="50%"
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:fromDegrees="720"
             android:toDegrees="0" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Within my layout I then used for instance this ImageView which is used the progress-drawable.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/element_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/progress_medium_holo" />
```

[image: static progress circle]

But the result is a static circle-progress. Is there a way to animate that one by XML definition and using no code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `View` named `ProgressBar` that does exactly what you want.
Just use this instead of your `ImageView`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/element_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
```

Comment: So I don't need the drawable anyway. Funny when I'm starting at the wrong side.

Comment: Not a bad idea though, I have encountered several devices as a developer that simply will NOT show a ProgressBar. It's in the layout, set to VISIBLE, but doesn't matter. I started looking for a replacement to Android's unreliable ProgressBar...

Answer (score 5):

In order to create a customized progress indicator (rotating progress circle, in your case)

1. Create a layout file(.xml) or use an image (drawable) for roatating circle. Put it in drawable folder in res.
2. Use this drawable as a source to the imageview in the layout for loading indicator.
3. Use this imageview by inflating and call following startLoadingAnimation() on it.Similarly you can stop the animation once your job is done by simply calling stopLoadingAnimation() on it.

You will have to use animation to make it rotate.

```
// start the loading animation

public void startLoadingAnimation(Context context) {
  Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
    R.anim.anim_rotate);
  rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
  mImgView.startAnimation(rotate);
}

// stop the loading animation
public void stopLoadingAnimation(){
  mImgView.clearAnimation();
}
```

`anim_rotate.xml` put this file in `anim` folder in `res`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="0"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
  android:toDegrees="360"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="500"
  android:startOffset="0"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, but in that solution I need some lines of codes. The ProgressBar of the other answer was more suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for progress_medium_holo.xml.
In my case a standard ProgressBar (for API 23) was not visible, I tryed many variations, only horizontal bar styled progressbars were visible. Then I copied progress_medium_holo.xml and linked drawables from the folder sdk\platforms\android-xx\data\res\drawable and eventually got:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_medium_holo"/>
```