# Progress bar set visiblity using grid view images gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview

Hello everyone i have an issue with the progress bar. I tried  to make a gallery view, all the images shown in grid view.but the issue is that, when all the images is loaded the progress bar did not gone, check the code
  I am using Rotate-loading as a Progress bar

**Updated**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;


RotateLoading rotateLoading;
int count;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;

}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_gallery,parent,false);
        imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(380,480));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

       // rotateLoading=(RotateLoading)convertView.findViewById(R.id.rotateloading);
        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Loading Data","Please wait.....",false,false);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }
    String url = null;
   url=getItem(position);


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal)
            .centerCrop()
            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 //   rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   // rotateLoading.stop();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                    //rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //rotateLoading.stop();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .crossFade()
            .into(imageView);
    return convertView;
}

// Keep all Images in array
public String[] mThumbIds = {
        "http://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Wide-wallpaper-nature-480x800-In-Wallpaper-HD-1366x768-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "http://greenywallpapers.com/wallpapers/10/275050-nature-wallpapers-720x1280.jpg",
        "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-wallpaper-nature-480x800-For-Wallpapers-Image-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Best-wallpaper-nature-480x800-In-Windows-Wallpaper-Themes-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "https://idealphotography.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Highres-wallpaper-nature-480x800-About-Windows-7-Wallpaper-with-wallpaper-nature-480x800-Download-HD-Wallpaper.jpg",
        "http://freewallpaper-background.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/M-3.jpg",
        "http://naturewallpaperfree.com/mobile/sky/nature-wallpaper-480x800-127-96fbd452.jpg",

};

}
```

this is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    />
<com.victor.loading.rotate.RotateLoading
    android:id="@+id/rotateloading"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    app:loading_width="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:loading_color="#ffffff"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>        
    </RelativeLayout>
[![Check the image][1]][1]
in the image the picture loads but the progress bar did not stops and invisible.
```

Please solve the issue.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vqyp.jpg
```

Comment: No one answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

update your xml file

```
  <com.victor.loading.rotate.RotateLoading
  android:id="@+id/rotateloading"
  android:layout_width="80dp"
  android:layout_height="80dp"
  app:loading_width="5dp"
  app:loading_color="#ffffff"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

and in your getView() method,

```
        rotateLoading.start();
        rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(url)
        .thumbnail(0.5f)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .fitCenter()
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);            
                rotateLoading.stop();

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                rotateLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rotateLoading.stop();

                return false;
            }
        })
        .crossFade()
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
but the error remain same. progress bar remain visible,

Comment: the progress bar invisible for few images but not for all. please solve my issue

Comment: Have you tried uaing normal ProgressBar instead of your custom RotateLoading ?

Comment: when i use default progressBar then it remains on the screen and the images loaded

Comment: any particular reason progress remain on screeen and the image loaded...

Answer (score 0):

I created a library that shows a progress over an imageview: [PowerfulImageView](https://github.com/stefanosiano/PowerfulImageView).

Import it, adding to gradle this line

```
compile 'com.stefanosiano:powerlessimageview:0.3.1'
```

Then change your xml with this:

```
<com.stefanosiano.powerfulimageview.PowerfulImageView
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    app:piv_progress_mode="circular" />
```

Then change your getView method to:

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PowerfulImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_gallery,parent,false);
        imageView=(PowerfulImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(380,480));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    } else {
        imageView = (PowerfulImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }
    imageView.changeProgressMode(PivProgressMode.CIRCULA‌​R);
    String url = null;
   url=getItem(position);


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(android.R.drawable.progress_indeterminate_horizontal)
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .into(imageView);
    return convertView;
}
```

Let me know if everything works fine :)

Comment: probably I'm late with this answer :D