# ProgressBar GridView Item

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am using a ProgressBar library with Glide to animate dots indicators while each item in GridView is loading, this works fine but I cannot hide the ProgressBar for each item that completed the download.

Strange behavior is that whichever item completes, its loading will result in the progressbar hiding only for the last item, the progressbar will continue to animate endlessly for all other completed items.

In summary I would like the progressbar to have the same behavior as a Gilde placeholder.

XML Code:

```
        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
                android:id="@+id/avi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:indicatorColor="@color/skyblue"
                app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator"
                style="@style/AVLoadingIndicatorView.Small"
                />
```

```
public CustomAdapter_GridViewMainFile(ActivityVideo_Cloud contextActivity, String[] stringArr_File, String[] stringArr_Date) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            context = contextActivity;
            strArr_File = stringArr_File;
            strArr_Date = stringArr_Date;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (strArr_File != null) {
                return strArr_File.length;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            AVLoadingIndicatorView avi;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            holder = new Holder();

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_video_gridview_single_checkbox, null);
            }

            holder.avi = convertView.findViewById(R.id.avi);

            Glide.with(getBaseContext())
                    .load(strArr_File[position])
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.avi.hide();

                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.avi.hide();

                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(holder.ivImage);

            ...
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306315/7972851) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454860/7972851) out

Comment: @grrigore your link to the solutions work fine for ProgressBar but I'm using a library progressbar: com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView

Comment: Did you try to use `avi.smoothToHide();`?