# Showing a Progress bar while loading image using Coil?

Tags: android, kotlin, image-loading, coil

How to show a progress bar while fetching image from URL in **Coil**.?

Answer (score 4):

Use [ImageRequest.Listener](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.request/-image-request/-listener/index.html)

Example:

```kt
val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
    .data(url)
    .listener(
        onStart = {
            // set your progressbar visible here
        },
        onSuccess = { request, metadata ->
            // set your progressbar invisible here
        }
    )
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(request)
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried only in Compose but I think you can use it [like Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306315/16279195)

Set the progress bar as placeholder

```kotlin
val circularProgressDrawable = CircularProgressDrawable(this)
circularProgressDrawable.strokeWidth = 5f
circularProgressDrawable.centerRadius = 30f
circularProgressDrawable.start()

imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg") {
    crossfade(true)
    placeholder(circularProgressDrawable)
    transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating app with jetpack compose then you don't need to do manual stuff,

you can use the builtin [SubcomposeAsyncImage](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#subcomposeasyncimage) provided by the library from version [`2.0.0-rc01`](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha07---january-30-2022)

```
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
    model = image,
    contentDescription = "",
    loading = { 
        CircularProgressIndicator(color = Color.Black) 
    },
)
```

Comment: SubcomposeAsyncImage has bad performance and is not recommended for the the Lists

Comment: thank you @AnmolSinghSahi for information

Answer (score 2):

I didn't work with Coil, but I suggest you may do the next:

```
// Before request run on the needed method
yourProgressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
.data("https://www.example.com/image.jpg")
.target { drawable ->
    yourProgressbar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}.build()   

val disposable = imageLoader.enqueue(request)
```

Here is [official doc's example](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/#requests)

Answer (score 0):

**Here what i am doing, it is working fine as expected**

```
 binding.circularProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
 binding.ivTeamPic.load(url) {
      target {
           binding.circularProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
           binding.ivTeamPic.setImageDrawable(it)
      }
 }
```