# Image view in android studio is showing in xml layout but not showing in app

Tags: android, xml

Image view in android studio is showing in xml layout but it is not showing in the app after run I tried every solution available but not got the solution to my problem.

I'm making a simple meme share app in which there will be two buttons share and next , after clicking next button another meme appears I used an random meme api I have not completed the app ( not added function for next button and share button  ) just to check whether meme image is showing or not I ran my code successfully it was installed on my phone, buttons are showing but image is not showing only white background

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.memeshare

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    loadMeme()
}

private fun loadMeme(){

  var memeImageview = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://i.redd.it/bi9tnlxmqlr71.jpg"


    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,null,
        { response ->

          val url = response.getString("url")
            Glide.with(this).load(url).into(memeImageview)
        },
        {  },
    )

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
}
fun shareMeme(view: View) {

}

fun nextMeme(view: View) {

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/shareButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/share"
    android:padding="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:onClick="shareMeme"/>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:width="0dp"
    android:padding="32dp"
    android:text="@string/next"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:onClick="nextMeme"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[It look like this in layout]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CarzW.jpg)

Comment: Show your code where you load an image in the ImageView. Note that the tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" only works in Android Studio but not while running the app.

Comment: @MarioHuizinga Thanks for answering  I'm making a simple meme share app in which there will be two buttons share and next, after clicking next button another meme appears I used an random meme api I have not completed the app ( not added function for next button and share button ) just to check whether meme image is showing or not I ran my code successfully it was installed on my phone share and next button are showing but the image is not showing, only white background. I updated the question with the code please help.

Comment: Try to make the code in your question better readable: edit the question and follow the instructions on the right. Mark your code as code, no unnecessary empty lines, and with indent. Also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35306315/7493938

Comment: did you successfully get an image URL from API?

Comment: @MohakShah Yes API is loading images. I got the mistake and answered my question you can check it  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69477022/16655199

Comment: okay, it sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content
```

And you need to add a source or background to the imageview.

```
android:background="@drawable/image"
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

Comment: @a_local_nobody I thought that `tools:srcCompat` is setting the image.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for the clarification. One downvote but still got something to learn. :-)

Comment: @a_local_nobody I updated the answer. Now I think its good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237889/discussion-between-akhil-nair-and-a-local-nobody).

Comment: @a_local_nobody I updated my question with the code please help.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for answering  I'm making a simple meme share app in which there will be two buttons share and next, after clicking next button another meme appears I used an random meme api I have not completed the app ( not added function for next button and share button ) just to check whether meme image is showing or not I ran my code successfully it was installed on my phone share and next button are showing but the image is not showing, only white background. I updated the question with the code please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to use tools:srcCompat.
So when you use tools, nothing will show in your app
You have to use
android:src="drawable/avatar"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who answered my question after a lot of struggle to find why my image view is not loading I got the mistake, actually what I did wrong was in

```
val url = "https://i.redd.it/bi9tnlxmqlr71.jpg"
```

I put the image link in `val url` instead of API link which is
"https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"

So the correct one is :

```
val url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
```

After this correction, my meme is loading.

Also, `"tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"` is only used for debugging, it doesn't do anything when you run the app.

Correct code,

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.memeshare
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        loadMeme()
    }

   private fun loadMeme(){

        var memeImageview = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
// ...

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
       val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
               Request.Method.GET, url,null,
               {
                   response ->
                   val url = response.getString("url")
                   Glide.with(this).load(url).into(memeImageview)
               },
               {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
               }
               )


       queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)



   }

    fun nextMeme(view: View) {
        loadMeme()
    }

    fun shareMeme(view: View) {}


// Add the request to the RequestQueue.

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"/>

    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/share"
        android:padding="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:onClick="shareMeme"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="190dp"
        android:padding="32dp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:onClick="nextMeme"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```